# Most efficient way to map two arrays of objects to prepare for 'upload'

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I wasn't sure how to word it in a couple of words.

I'm currently dealing with a situation where the user uploads a .csv or excel file, and the data must be mapped properly to prepare for a batch upload. It will make more sense as you read the code below!

First step: The user uploads the .csv/excel file, it's transformed into an array of objects. Generally the first array will be the headers.

The data will look like the below(including headers). This will be anywhere between 100 items to up to ~100,000 items:

```
const DUMMY_DATA = [
['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'],
['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'],
['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']
]
```

Once this is uploaded, the user will map out each field to the proper schema. This could either be all of the fields or only a select few.

For instance the user only wants to exclude the address portion except for zip code.
We would get back the 'mapped fields' array, renamed to the proper schema names (i.e. First Name => firstName):

```
const MAPPED_FIELDS = [firstName, lastName, company, email, phone, <empty>, <empty>, <empty>, zipCode]
```

I've made it so the indexes of the mapped fields will always match the 'headers'. So any unmapped headers will have an  value.

So in this scenario we know to only upload the data (of DUMMY_DATA) with the indexes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8].

We then get to the final part where we want to upload the proper fields for all the data, so we would have the properly mapped schemas from MAPPED_FIELDS matching the mapped values from DUMMY_DATA...

```
const firstObjectToBeUploaded = {
  firstName: 'Lambert',
  lastName: 'BeckHouse',
  company: 'StackOverflow',
  email: 'lbeckhouse@stackoverflow.com',
  phone: '512-555-1738',
  zipCode: '78721'
}

try {
  await uploadData(firstObjectToBeUploaded)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

All the data will be sent to an AWS lambda function written in Node.js to handle the upload / logic.

I'm struggling a bit on how to implement this efficiently as the data can get quite large.

Comment: When you say `<empty>` do you mean an empty string, or a `null` value or ???

Comment: It is currently a null value but that can easily be changed if needed. The main reason that the I included <empty> is so we can quickly know which indexes of the data should be included. For instance if we have MAPPED_FIELDS = [firstName, null, null, email, null...] we know to only upload the data array with indexes 0 and 3.  Please let me know if I'm doing a poor job of explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `DUMMY_DATA` array (minus the headers) into a set of arrays with values being

1. the key from `MAPPED_FIELDS` and
2. the corresponding `DUMMY_DATA` value with the same index

You can then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those arrays to remove `null` keys and turn them into objects using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const DUMMY_DATA = [
['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'],
['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'],
['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']
]

const MAPPED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'company', 'email', 'phone', null, null, null, 'zipCode']

const objectsToUpload = DUMMY_DATA.slice(1).map(data =>
  Object.fromEntries(MAPPED_FIELDS
    .map((key, idx) => [key, data[idx]])
    .filter(a => a[0])
  )
)

console.log(objectsToUpload)
```

Comment: tried this in my code, worked great! Really appreciate your help my man, saved my brain from a lot of further frying

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for some performance gains at larger array sizes you can apply the same logic as Nick's answer but implemented in standard `for` loops.

##### for

```js
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'],
  ['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'],
  ['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']
];

const MAPPED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'company', 'email', 'phone', null, null, null, 'zipCode'];

const fieldLength = MAPPED_FIELDS.length;
const dataLength = DUMMY_DATA.length;

const objectsToUpload = [];
for (let i = 1; i < dataLength; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < fieldLength; j++) {
    if (MAPPED_FIELDS[j] !== null) {
      obj[MAPPED_FIELDS[j]] = DUMMY_DATA[i][j];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}

console.log(objectsToUpload);
```

##### for...of

Here isolating the [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries?retiredLocale=nl) of the `MAPPED_FIELDS` array once before the loop to avoid repeated generation of the entries iterator and simply skipping `null` keys rather than filtering them later. Destructuring and the possibly the iterator creation/spread seems to put this below Nick's for small arrays, but faster on larger arrays (Chrome based browser tests).

```js
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'],
  ['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'],
  ['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']
];

const MAPPED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'company', 'email', 'phone', null, null, null, 'zipCode'];
const MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES = [...MAPPED_FIELDS.entries()];

const objectsToUpload = [];
for (const datum of DUMMY_DATA.slice(1)) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [idx, key] of MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES) {
    if (key !== null) {
      obj[key] = datum[idx];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}

console.log(objectsToUpload);
```

---

Rough benchmark below with results as follows on my machine.

```
for          1,000: 0.400ms
for...of     1,000: 2.900ms
entries      1,000: 1.700ms

for         10,000: 4.100ms
for...of    10,000: 11.700ms
entries     10,000: 13.900ms

for        100,000: 30.200ms
for...of   100,000: 56.500ms
entries    100,000: 100.200ms
```

```js
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'],
  ['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'],
  ['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']
];

const MAPPED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'company', 'email', 'phone', null, null, null, 'zipCode'];

function makeBigData(size) {
  const [header, ...data] = DUMMY_DATA;
  const r = [header];
  for (let l = 0; l < size; l += 1) {
    r.push([...data[Math.round(Math.random())]]);
  }
  return r;
}

let data = makeBigData(1000);
console.time('for          1,000');
let objectsToUpload = [];
let fieldLength = MAPPED_FIELDS.length, dataLength = data.length;
for (let i = 1; i < dataLength; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < fieldLength; j++) {
    if (MAPPED_FIELDS[j] !== null) {
      obj[MAPPED_FIELDS[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for          1,000');

data = makeBigData(1000);
console.time('for...of     1,000');
objectsToUpload = [];
let MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES = [...MAPPED_FIELDS.entries()];
for (const datum of data.slice(1)) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [i, key] of MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES) {
    if (key !== null) {
      obj[key] = datum[i];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for...of     1,000');

data = makeBigData(1000);
console.time('entries      1,000');
objectsToUpload = data.slice(1).map(data =>
  Object.fromEntries(MAPPED_FIELDS
    .map((key, idx) => [key, data[idx]])
    .filter(a => a[0])
  )
)
console.timeEnd('entries      1,000');

console.log();

data = makeBigData(10000);
console.time('for         10,000');
objectsToUpload = [];
fieldLength = MAPPED_FIELDS.length, dataLength = data.length;
for (let i = 1; i < dataLength; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < fieldLength; j++) {
    if (MAPPED_FIELDS[j] !== null) {
      obj[MAPPED_FIELDS[j]] = data[i];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for         10,000');

data = makeBigData(10000);
console.time('for...of    10,000');
objectsToUpload = [];
MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES = [...MAPPED_FIELDS.entries()];
for (const datum of data.slice(1)) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [i, key] of MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES) {
    if (key !== null) {
      obj[key] = datum[i];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for...of    10,000');

data = makeBigData(10000);
console.time('entries     10,000');
objectsToUpload = data.slice(1).map(data =>
  Object.fromEntries(MAPPED_FIELDS
    .map((key, idx) => [key, data[idx]])
    .filter(a => a[0])
  )
)
console.timeEnd('entries     10,000');

console.log();

data = makeBigData(100000);
console.time('for        100,000');
objectsToUpload = [];
fieldLength = MAPPED_FIELDS.length, dataLength = data.length;
for (let i = 1; i < dataLength; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < fieldLength; j++) {
    if (MAPPED_FIELDS[j] !== null) {
      obj[MAPPED_FIELDS[j]] = data[i];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for        100,000');

data = makeBigData(100000);
console.time('for...of   100,000');
objectsToUpload = [];
MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES = [...MAPPED_FIELDS.entries()];
for (const datum of data.slice(1)) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [i, key] of MAPPED_FIELDS_ENTRIES) {
    if (key !== null) {
      obj[key] = datum[i];
    }
  }
  objectsToUpload.push(obj);
}
console.timeEnd('for...of   100,000');

data = makeBigData(100000);
console.time('entries    100,000');
objectsToUpload = data.slice(1).map(data =>
  Object.fromEntries(MAPPED_FIELDS
    .map((key, idx) => [key, data[idx]])
    .filter(a => a[0])
  )
)
console.timeEnd('entries    100,000');
```

Comment: appreciate the addition! this is also working great.

Comment: Removing the filter stage should definitely make this faster.

Comment: Interesting that the functional approach is faster for shorter arrays. I guess its the benefit of compiled for loops.

Comment: On my laptop I get `for...of     1,000: 4.000ms
Nick         1,000: 4.000ms
for...of    10,000: 12.000ms
Nick        10,000: 10.000ms
for...of   100,000: 63.000ms
Nick       100,000: 92.000ms` - weird that longer arrays are faster but shorter slower. Also mine is faster up to 10k.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version of what Nick wrote would be to parse the `MAPPED_FIELDS` first, turning them into `[name, index]` pairs, and removing the ones with `null` names.  Then we can more efficiently scan and convert the objects.  It might look like this:

```js
const mapData = (fields, locs = Object .entries (fields) .filter (([_, k]) => k !== null)) => 
  ([headers, ...rows]) => rows .map (
    r => Object .assign (...locs .map (([i, n]) => ({[n]: r[i]})))
  )

const DUMMY_DATA = [ ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'], ['Lambert', 'Beckhouse', 'StackOverflow', 'lbeckhouse0@stackoverflow.com', '512-555-1738', '316 Arapahoe Way', 'Austin', 'TX', '78721'], ['Maryanna', 'Vassman', 'CDBABY', 'mvassman1@cdbaby.com', '479-204-8976', '1126 Troy Way', 'Fort Smith', 'AR', '72916']]

const MAPPED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'company', 'email', 'phone', null, null, null, 'zipCode'];

console .log (mapData (MAPPED_FIELDS) (DUMMY_DATA))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I think in terms of performance, this would fall between pilchard's `for-each` version and Nick's version.  But all of these are linear, so I don't think there's serious algorithmic concerns.  I would go with one of the simpler ones unless you have need to eke out all the performance possible.